# ActionScript 3.0 complex mp3 player

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, mp3

I'm writing and mp3 player in actionscript for my web site. The problem is, it needs also to download files. What i mean it'll download mp3 files from remote server via URLLoader.load() function probably. AS is not multithreaded so when downloading it blocks.

When thinking of solution I figured out, I can write to separate, let's call it modules(.swf) and one will be music player, other downloader and they can communicate via javascript.

How do I solve this problem regarding communication between .swfs?

Comment: You wrote "via URLLoader.load() function probably". Have you actually tried to use it? If you do, you'll find that it's asynchronous so it won't block your interface.

Comment: I do, but I tried using URLLoader1.load() and URLLoader2.load() at the same time and it seems they works one after another, not at the same time(or maybe i did something wrong:D) so I though it blocks...:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLLoader.load() will not block the UI. However, the browser and flash player will only allow 2 open connections to the same domain name so you will only be able to play one song, and download 1 song at a time.

Comment: Wow, that's good to know about connections(theoretically, will using proxy help?):D I know I can have Sound.load() and Sound.play() running at the same time, so using URLLoader.load() with above two, wouldn't be a problem?:D

Comment: I believe that by default FF and IE limit the user to 6 connections total, and 2 connections per host. This is a browser limit that flash player adheres to. So if you have 1 Sound.load() and 1 Sound.play() running, URLLoader.load() will block until one of them is complete. A quick way of getting around this would be to setup subdomains. Something like: streaming.mydomain.com and downloads.mydomain.com. This way you will get 2 connections per sub-domain.